# Android, strange behavior of fragment transaction replace()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-framelayout

I want to use a multipane layout for wider screens. The data is persisted with `SQL` and each fragment fetches the right data. The extra layout xml files are in resource directory folders.(i.e. layout-w500dp)
 But i have some strange behavior.
*It only seems to work after I select something and then press the back button.*
Atm I am using max two FrameLayouts but later I want to do it with four.
I check the level of the deepest selection and assign the fragments accordingly. (Here its only down to lvl 1, but later I need selections up to lvl3). 
**Here is what I want to achieve.**

[image: image 1]

**This gets called in `onCreate` and when a selection has been made.**

```
private void setScreens(){

  int i = getLowestSelection();//returns 0 when nothing is selected. 
  //And 1 if selection is made in lvl1 ...
  int p = 1;

  FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

   if (findViewById(R.id.fragtwo) != null) {
       p = 2;

       if (i == 1){
           SectionsScreen secondFragment = new SectionsScreen();
           transaction.replace(R.id.fragtwo,secondFragment);
       }
   }

  if (findViewById(R.id.fragone) != null) {
      if(p == 2){
          if (i == 0 ){
              StatuteScreen statuteScreenFragment = new StatuteScreen();
              transaction.replace(R.id.fragone,statuteScreenFragment);
          }
      }
      if (p == 1){
          if (i == 0){
              StatuteScreen statuteScreenFragment = new StatuteScreen();
              transaction.replace(R.id.fragone,statuteScreenFragment);
          }
          else if (i == 1){
              SectionsScreen sectionsScreenFragment = new SectionsScreen();
              transaction.replace(R.id.fragone,sectionsScreenFragment);
          }
      }
  }
   transaction.addToBackStack(null);
   transaction.commit();
 }
```

**It only works at the moment if I do the following.**

1. Start application = 1 fragment in portrait and landscape (this is the desired behavior)
2. Make selection in Portrait = nothing happens !!!!  (Here is the problem)
3. Switch to Landscape = 2 Fragments with the right selection (right behavior) 
   (if I make the initial selection in landscape I need to rotate to Portrait and back again)
4. Switch to Portrait = LvL 2 Fragment with right Data ( right behavior)
5. Press Back Button = LvL 1 Fragment (right behavior)
6. From now on I can switch between portrait to landscape orientation and i get the right behavior for selecting items in all orientations. Even on backpress in landscape showing only one fragment with lvl 1 when selection is taken away.

**Why am i getting this behavior?** 
**And is this the right approach in the firstplace?** 
Considering I want to extend this for further levels and screenWidths!
i.e.:

[image: image2]

will backstack function properly here? If anyone needs additional info, just say and i'll be happy to add it!

Comment: if you downvote. pls explain why, so i can improve the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. I save the selections in an Application Class and i instatiate that in `onCreate` but i need to reinstantiate before i get the current selection in the `getLowestSelection()` method